# How to write xml with data inside the lesser/greater than symbol?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have this sample xml file

```
<LTRP cd="1">
  <Customize>0</Customize>
  <Gud>0</Gud>
  <Kingaku>64500000</Kingaku>
  <Kingaku term="1" year="2017" month="0">0</Kingaku>
</LTRP>
```

and I got this code for that - providing that I already have the data needed

```
        Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        Dim dsProperty As New DsikopgmProperty
        Dim xmlFileName As String = "filename"
        ' Create XmlWriter.
        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\FILES\" + xmlFileName, settings)
            ' Begin writing.
            writer.WriteStartDocument()

            For Each record In records
                writer.WriteStartElement("LTRP cd", dsrecords.BunruiCd)
                writer.WriteElementString("Customize", "")
                writer.WriteElementString("Gud", "0")
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            Next

            ' End document.
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
        End Using
```

I would want to know what particular part of my code should I change to have these output

```
<LTRP cd="1">
</LTRP>

<Kingaku term="1" year="2017" month="0">0</Kingaku>
```

While I'm at it, can anyone also tell me what do we call the `<>` symbol other than `greater than` and `lesser than`?

Comment: yeah. the first Kingaku is `<kingaku></kingaku>` only and the second one has the data inside like `<kingaku term = "" ></kingaku>` @Blam

Comment: Elements are the <>. What you are looking are attributes. Look for something similar to WriteAttribute. I haven't used that class before but you can find [the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @the_lotus thanks, i'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modification I made to come up with the output desired

```
    Dim writer As XmlWriter = Nothing

    writer = XmlWriter.Create("sampledata.xml")
    writer.WriteStartElement("LTRP")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("cd", "1")

    writer.WriteElementString("Customize", "0")
    writer.WriteElementString("Gud", "0")

    writer.WriteElementString("Kingaku", "64500000")
    writer.WriteStartElement("Kingaku")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("term", "1")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("year", "2017")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("month", "0")
    writer.WriteValue("0")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteElementString("rate", "10")
    writer.WriteEndElement()

    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()
```

For the source, [click here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkd34zdt(v=vs.110).aspx)
Thanks to [@the_lotus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130611/the-lotus) for that significant comment.

*Note: I only used constant values for testing. It could be replaced with variables to loop many records.*